# Object gets logged in the console, but comes out empty when calling API

Tags: javascript, express

There's something I don't understand when running the following piece of code:

```js
const handleCalculations = async ({
    configuration,
    product,
}) => {
    const configurations = [];
    const results = [];
    
    /*
    configurations get populated with elements
    */
    
    await Promise.all(configurations.map(async (configuration) => {
        const calcResult = await getResults(configuration);
        results.push({ calcResult });           // option #1: working
        results[configuration.id] = calcResult; // option #2: not working - empty output
    }));
    
    console.log({ results });
    
    return {
        message: 'OK',
        result: results,
    };
};
```

Having option #1 enabled, I receive an array of arrays, and they're distinguished only by `result` key, which is a bit problematic when there are many arrays and one has to navigate between them pretty quickly. That's why I tried to enable option #2: that would prepend every array with a unique `ID` key. And this is how it's logged in the console, outside of the `Promise`:

```
{
    results: [
        'a389': [...],
        'f31a': [...],
        'd50d': [...]
    ]
}
```

However, returned value is empty: it's just:

```
{
    "message": "OK",
    "result": []
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You aren't `await`ing the `handleCalculations` call

Comment: `results` is an array, not an object. When you log it, you don't see the named properties.

Comment: Use `option #2` along with initilizing `const results = {};`

Comment: Yep, {}'s helped. Please consider adding this as the answer.